# Drupal 7: print field to region in node--type.tpl.php file

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

In Drupal 6, it was so easy to print content to an existing region using the following:

```
<?php
  drupal_set_content('left-sidebar', $field_MY_FIELD_rendered);
?>
```

I've been searching and searching for how to do this in Drupal 7 after finding out `drupal_add_region_content()` doesn't work and I'm at a loss.

I can get the exact output I'm looking for using `$output = render($content['field_MY_FIELD']);`, but I see no way to output that to a block without having to write a hook in a separate module or some such thing.

Any ideas on how to output $output to a region using node--type.tpl.php?

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: `drupal_add_region_content()` works fine (core itself uses the function to assign page content to the necessary regions). Where are you calling it from?

Comment: @Clive, thanks but I think it only works for core (see http://drupal.org/node/713462). I'm calling it from node--type.tpl.php.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting **field--field_myfield.tpl.php** in your templates directory?